# GPU Support on Ubuntu VServer ? (for running OBS)

Tags: drivers, video, gpu, support, openvz

I set up an Ubuntu VServer, installed Open Broadcaster Software, and wanted to do a little radio stream for YouTube.

If I start OBS it shows me a `Failed to initialize video. Your GPU may not be supported, or your graphics drivers may need to be updated` message.

Is there any way to simulate the GPU - Driver or does anyone have a hint for me?

This VServer runs with OpenVZ 7, but I rented it, so I can't access the settings of the virtualization software.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command it works for me:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs-studio
```

Comment: I am using digital ocean ubuntu 18 droplet and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

For Xubuntu 18.04 working but with:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs
```

see this snapshot

[image: obs in Xubuntu 18.04]

Note: I am using fluxbox Window Manager

Thanks for this command

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to reinstall the GPU again and reboot. After that I just started OBS Studio with no further commands and it worked.